# How do you reference a process.env variable in HTML <script src="" ? React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, webpack, environment-variables, gitignore

I have a react app and am using dotenv-webpack to manage my API keys.

I have:
- created a .env with the API keys and gitignored it.
- required and added dotenv as a plugin in webpack.config.js.

After that, I've been able to reference one of the keys in a .js file by using process.env.api_key. But I am having problems trying to reference it in index.html in the script tag.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/48938155eb24b4ccdde09426066869504c6dab3c/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=process.env.GOOGLEMAP_API_KEY"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

How do I reference the process.env.API_key here?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API_KEY]"></script>
```

I have tried using backquotes that work in .js file, like so `${API_KEY}`, but that does not work in the .html file.

Comment: you can't, use js to make a script element...

Comment: check my updated answer + example below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I put the following code in componentWillMount where the map renders
>   and it worked (at least in development: const API_KEY =
>   process.env.GOOGLEMAP_API_KEY; const script =
>   document.createElement('script'); script.src =
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${API_KEY};
>   document.head.append(script);

I was able to get this to work using the code posted by bigmugcup in the comments above. I did not modify the webpack.config.js file.

Answer (score 27):

If you're already using create-react-app, this is already available by updating to

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%REACT_APP_API_KEY%"></script>
```

as it says in [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html)

> You can also access the environment variables starting with REACT_APP_ in the public/index.html.

Comment: more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744375/create-react-app-using-environment-variables-in-index-html

Answer (score 18):

## Solution

You can't reference the `process.env` variable directly inside `html`.

Create your own template from `index.html` and replace the api url with a parameter.

## HtmlWebpackPlugin

> Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.

You can either let the plugin generate an HTML file for you, supply your own template using lodash templates or use your own loader.

#### Webpack.config.js

[HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) allows you to create and pass parameters to your template:

```
   const api_key = process.env.api_key;
   const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    
    module.exports = {
      entry: 'index.js',
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          inject: false,
          template: './template.html',

          // Pass the full url with the key!
          apiUrl: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${api_key}`,

        });
      ]
    }
```

#### template.html

Inside the template you can access to the parameter:

```
<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.apiUrl %>"></script>
```

See: [Writing Your Own Templates](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates)

## Notes

> This is a modified answer from this [comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3105#issuecomment-252312656), please read the full conversation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still not clear. Where do I add your code? I tried putting all of it in between the <script type="text/javascript"></script> tags but I get "Reference error: process is not defined." I added the index.html above.

Comment: you can access to process from your `webpack.config` right?

Comment: I've access process in webpack.config by 'process.env.NODE_ENV.' Also, I have accessed process.env in another API call in a .js file. The problem is just accessing in index.html.

Comment: I put the following code in componentWillMount where the map renders and it worked (at least in development: const API_KEY = process.env.GOOGLEMAP_API_KEY;   const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${API_KEY}`; document.head.append(script);

Comment: **How to access htmlWebpackPlugin.options.apiUrl this variable inside script like this** `<script>  const some_variable = htmlWebpackPlugin.options.apiUrl; if(some_variable) { do something } </script>` . Another question is like how does  <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.apiUrl %>"></script> here show does this syntax works I mean **htmlWebpackPlugin** how do we get this variable context here.

Answer (score 15):

The simple way you can use

in HTML

```
<p>%NODE_ENV%</p>
```

and in script

```
<script>
if('%NODE_ENV%' === 'production') {
.... some code
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the issue how to set attribute value conditionally, after a couple of minutes, I actually found a way to handle this case, which I am listing below. And its handled by **HtmlWebpackPlugin**. This snippet will also help you referencing environment variable in HTML file.

**Environment setup**

- I am using Create React App, which has HtmlWebpackPlugin within modules, will be visible upon ejecting the application.
- My App is in default state i-e not ejected

**Environment Variable Definition**

I am setting environment variable [**APP_ENV**] in scripts property of **Package.json** file., which looks like

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "set APP_ENV=development&& react-scripts start",
    "build:prod": "set APP_ENV=production&& react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

**Referencing varialble in HTML file**

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://<%= process.env.APP_ENV ==='production' ? 'prod.domain': 'dev.domain'%>/main.min.css" />
```