# Create React App: using environment variables in index.html

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Is there a way to inject environment variables, e.g. `REACT_APP_MY_API` into the `index.html` file?

According to [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1440), it can be done, but I can't seem to get it to work.

### .env

```
REACT_APP_MY_API=https://something.com
```

### index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log("%REACT_APP_MY_API%") // undefined 
  console.log("%NODE_ENV%") // development
</script>
```

Comment: For future readers, here's a [link to the relevant docs page](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html) (that now exists).

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I just tried with an (almost) new CRA setup and it works.

```
<head>
  <title>React App</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   console.log("%REACT_APP_TEST%") // OK
   console.log("%NODE_ENV%") // development
  </script>
</head>
```

Did you try restarting the server?
I just tried changing the test variable with your example and it works if you restart the development server.

As someone pointed out in the comments, the official documentation of CRA has [a section](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html) about that.

Comment: Very strange, I had restarted and it still wasn't working. Working now, thanks!

Answer (score 38):

Make sure you restart your create-react-app when adding variables into the .env file

Also make sure you have >= react-scripts@0.9

I use .env variables for the meta title of a site with various language versions of the build:

`<title>%REACT_APP_SITE_TITLE%</title>`

Comment: This is only applied at build time.

Answer (score 31):

From the docs ([here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html)):

- make sure your `react-scripts` dependency version is equal or greater than `0.0.9`
- create a `.env` file at the same level of your `package.json`
- make sure all you variables start with `REACT_APP_`; for example `REACT_APP_TITLE`
- use them in you js / ts code using `process.env.REACT_APP_XXX`
- or in you html code surrounding it with `%` ie `<title>%REACT_APP_TITLE%</title>`
- **restart your development server** / re-compile your app when making changes to your `.env` file

Answer (score 4):

If you want environmental variable in script tag, put the variable in quote:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%REACT_APP_MAP_API%&v=3.exp&libraries=places" async
    ></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution in 2022**

In create react app I have `.env.production`, `.env.staging` and `.env.development`.

In all `.env` files I have `REACT_APP_FB_ID`.

So in `index.html` I just use `<meta name="fb:app_id" content="%REACT_APP_FB_ID%" />`

Comment: Docs are [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used)

Answer (score 1):

I tried like this
'NODE_ENV=development npm start' 
and it works well