# In a ReactJS app, how to substitute env vars from the global environment into my index.html file?

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables

I have a ReactJS 17 app, in which I would like to substitute environment variables from my global environment into my `src/index.html` file.  However, we're not using `.env` files, as this answer suggests -- [Create React App: using environment variables in index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744375/create-react-app-using-environment-variables-in-index-html) .  Here is the `src/index.html` file ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover" />
    
    ...
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="512x512">
    <script src="%REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL%"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
```

In my shell, I can see the env var in my global environment

```
$ echo $REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL
http://thirdpartyurl.com
```

I am running my application in development mode, installing using `npm i` and running using `npm run start`.  However, the substitution above is never made, and the page is getting rendered with

```
<script src="%REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL%"></script>
```

**Edit:**

This is a development environment, so hot re-loading and all of that.  Here is how I "start" in package.json

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.development.js"
```

**Edit 2:** Not sure if this matters, but this is in my webpack file ...

my package.json ...

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My desc",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watchAll",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.production.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.development.js",
...
```

Here's the webpack.development.js file ...

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common');

const WEBPACK_WATCH_POLLING = process.env.WEBPACK_WATCH_POLLING === '1';

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    hot: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0', 
    port: 8080,
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  // This is needed for docker-on-windows.
  watchOptions: !WEBPACK_WATCH_POLLING
    ? undefined
    : {
        poll: 1000,
      },
});
```

Here's my webpack.common file ...

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve('src'),
      '@sb': path.resolve('.storybook'),
      '@static': path.resolve('static'),
      common: path.resolve('src/components/common'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            babelrc: true,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'icons/',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'fonts/',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL: "http://google.com"
      //filename: './index.html',
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'src/manifest.json' },
        { from: 'static/**/*.{png,svg,ico}', flatten: true },
      ],
    }),
    new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.InjectManifest({
      swSrc: './src/service-worker.js',
    }),
    new EnvironmentPlugin([
      'NODE_ENV',
      'REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL',
    ]),
  ],
};
```

And lastly, my src/index.tsx file ...

```
import './monitor';
import * as serviceWorker from './sw-registration';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app/App';
import './i18n.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <App />
    </React.Suspense>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.register();
```

Comment: Do you use .env files?

Comment: No, we do not use .env files.

Comment: @Dave, are you building your project with webpack?

Comment: You're 100% sure that the environment variable is available permanently and not just in a particular shell instance?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use .env files?

Comment: I'd love to, but it's not my decision.

Comment: One possible solution which may or may not fit your usecase. You could create a small api server which is responsible for serving a GET /config that returns a json. Your client html can then make a http request to get the config data. The config data will contain ur environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possible approaches depending on your environment and build tools.

I suppose the most convenient approach for you will be to supply them to your project at build time.

1. You can generate your `index.html` file dynamically(by using a template engine or a simple script that executes the job for you) and append the required variables manually by reading them from the environment.
2. Or the more elegant solution - integrate this step into your build tools. If you're using `webpack` to build your bundle, you can use the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to build your `index.html` file for you fed with all the env data you need.

In order to do that, create a simple `.ejs` or `.html` file that you're gonna use as a template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      ...
      <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.thirdPartyData.url %>"></script>
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

Then, in your `webpack.config.js` you setup the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` like so:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: '<PATH_TO_YOUR_TEMPLATE>',
            thirdPartyData: {
                url: process.env.<YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE>
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

`Webpack` will fetch the variables from the environment(through `node`) and will build your `index.html` for you based on your template file. You can supply arbitrary data to the plugin which you can then read in the templates from the `htmlWebpackPlugin.options` property. You can learn more about [HtmlWebpackPlugin here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin).

Take note that in order to **change** the environment variables in the code itself, you'll have to do a rebuild through `webpack`, which is understandable.

This solution doesn't require you to use `create-react-app` or `.env` files, nor does it require a server/server-rendering to do the job for you. Take note that it also works completely outside the context of the react app(you're not in the react app itself, you're working directly over the `.html` markup).

---

Another possible approach is to supply the environment variables through `npm scripts` using the `--env` flag but this will be inconvenient for you to integrate as it will require some additional work.

---

**EDIT after comments**:

Here is a [minimal sample sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wood-otxtz). The provided code **won't work** inside codesandbox itself due to the way it executes the scripts but if you duplicate the provided example on your machine it will do what it is supposed to. In order to test it, you simply need the `index.html`, the `webpack.config.json`, the `package.json` and a dummy `index.js`. I've striped out the react related code for brevity.

Simply download the codesandbox sample, run `npm install` and then `npm start`.

Then you can migrate the approach to your specific code base.

---

**EDIT 2**:

Okay, I found the issue. Your `html-loader` interferes with the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and doesn't substitute the variables in the template. You'll notice if you comment out the `html-loader` in your webpack.config that the transformation works. So, the simplest solution will be:

1. Create a new `index.html.ejs` file and put it next to your `index.html`. This is an actual proper `ejs` template. Put the current contents of your `index.html` there:

`index.html.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="512x512">
    <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL %>"></script>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    ...
</body>

</html>
```

2. In your `webpack.common.js` point the `template` property in `HtmlWebpackPlugin` config to lead to that template:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html.ejs',
    REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL: "http://google.com"
})
```

At this point you can even delete the `index.html` altogether, as it is going to get generated by the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` plugin.

This way you preserve your `html-loader` transformations(if you actually need it for anything) and you get the interpolated html file.

Comment: The '<%= htmlWebpack' is still being echoed out literally, so I'm trying to figure out the issue.  What am I supposed to put for "<PATH_TO_YOUR_TEMPLATE"?  Right now I have 'template: './src/index.html','.

Comment: `filename` will be the "compilated" result `.html`. `template` is the file that contains the.. template(the first code sample in my answer). Basically, webpack takes the file located at `template` and substitutes all the variable strings with the actual data and saves the compilated result at `filename`. In order for this to work, you have to build your code with webpack.

Comment: This is in a deveoopment environment, so there's no "build" step, just a "start", step (I edited the question to include the start command).  Can I still do the substitution in this scenario and if so, what value do I use for "<PATH_TO_YOUR_TEMPLATE>"?

Comment: @Dave Yes, of course. You use the exact same approach. For the value of `template` you supply the path to your `index.html` which contains the placeholder string for the env variable(the `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.thirdPartyData.url %>`). You can skip supplying the `filename` property altogether. When you run `npm start`, `webpack-dev-server` will read the configuration file and will build the html for you.

Comment: @Dave I've added a code sample that you can try as an edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  It's still not doing the substitutions, not sure if taht's because I have my "index.html" file in my root "src" directory.  Is there any way to get webpack to display some kind of debugging output if it is actually attempting the substitutions at all?  Or some way to cause it to fail if it can't find the file in question?  At least then I woudl know why it isn't doing the substitution.

Comment: @Dave Can you provide a sample of your code that we can test against? Just the relevant parts - the `index.html`, `package.json` and the webpack configuration file/files. You can strip anything else. Just preserve your actual directory structure. A simple codesandbox like the one in my answer will do.

Comment: K, I "think" I've added what you were asking for ... relevant parts of package, webpack files and index.tsx (index.html is the same as in my question).  Let me know what else I should add (or remove).  Thanks.

Comment: @Dave I've added a new edit to my answer with a solution.

Comment: Really great stuff.  Wish I could give you 1000!

Answer (score 0):

You can add [temporary environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-temporary-environment-variables-in-your-shell) in your shell which your package manager (npm or yarn) can use to build the React app.

---

You can do it in these ways:

1. By adding a temporary variable:

```sh
$ REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL=http://thirdpartyurl.com npm start
```

Or

2. By adding a temporary variable (**but from a global shell variable**) :

```sh
$ REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL=$REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL npm start
```

Assuming that "REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL" is defined as global env variable (prints a value for `$ echo $REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL`)

---

You can similarly run other npm / yarn commands such as "build", "test" etc. And it will replace the value in HTML (`<script src="%REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL%"></script>`).

There are subtle differences when using different Operating Systems. Above examples are for [Linux / Macos Bash](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#linux-macos-bash) shell.

#### Edit:

If you don't want to write these long env vars each time with npm start or build command, you can write these in package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL=$REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL REACT_APP_ANOTHER_VAR=$REACT_APP_ANOTHER_VAR react-scripts start",
    ...
  }
```

---

If you are not using **react-scripts** but using **webpack-dev-server** directly, here is how to achieve the same:

1. **Write this** in your html file:

```html
<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL %>"></script>
```

2. **Add** "REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL" in `HtmlWebpackPlugin` options:

```js
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveAppPath = (relativePath) => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: "./src/index.html", // OR resolveAppPath("src/index.html")
      REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL: process.env.REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL, // HERE
    }),
  ],
  // ...
```

3. **Do nothing** in your package.json script. Let it be like it was, maybe:

```js
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.development.js"
```

Comment: In your scenario where you are adding the env var as part of the "start" command, what is the way you would get this var to be substituted in the ReactJS src/index.html file?

Comment: When I do `npm start` after changing the "start" script as I have shown in my answer in **Edit**, it will read from **global** env vars and replace the values in HTML file (when written exactly the same as you have shown in your question i.e. `<script src="%REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_URL%"></script>`). I tested this, it worked perfectly, the only difference I see now is that you are not using *react-scripts* but using `webpack-dev-server` directly. React Scripts use webpack under the hood, but I did not test if it would work same with webpack (directly) as well.

Comment: @Dave Check my latest edit in my answer. I added for "webpack-dev-server" as well.

Comment: quick thing -- you have "fs.realpathSync(process.cwd())" -- where does "fs" come from?  Is that just "require('fs')"?

Comment: Yes. You need to imprt that from "path" and "fs" packages. const fs = require("fs"). const path = require("path")