# .env is not being read in create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, dotenv

I have created a react app using `create-react-app`. I'm using `react-admin` to develop my admin panel. I want to use some environment variables. Here's my `.env` file:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000
REACT_APP_BRAND=Guli
REACT_APP_SLOGAN=Financial transactions, redefined
```

And I also have `.env.test` and `.env.production` for staging and production environments, and I only override API URL in those files.

Now I want to use these variables inside my react app. I'm using them inside `index.html` and `DataProvider.js` that I use for `react-admin`.

In `index.html` I use:

```
<title>%REACT_APP_BRAND%</title>
```

and in `DataProvider` I use:

```
const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
// using apiUrl in the rest of DataProvider.js
```

The problem is that none of these variables are read from `.env` file. In `index.html` I see the title of my app to be exactly `%REACT_APP_BRAND%`, and the calls to my API go to `undefined/users` for example which means that `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` is not loaded.

What sould I do?

Comment: Are you using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: Hi, instead of `%REACT_APP_BRAND%` use `process.env.REACT_APP_BRAND`

Comment: Are you putting the `.env` files in the root of the project?

Comment: @SaatvikRamani, yeah I'm using `dotenv`. In fact I'm using `create-react-app` ro `CRA` which uses `dotenv`.

Comment: @MB_, but that should also work in HTML.

Comment: @SeanBoult, yeah they are in the root folder of the project, They are siblings to `package.json`.

Comment: @HosseinFallah after looking into it, react doesn't need you to use dotenv exclusively as it automatically loads all .env in your project root(Same as your index.js). I just tested this out.

Comment: @SaatvikRamani, I don't have added dependency to `dotenv` in my `package.json`. If react doesn't use it, then I also don't use it.

Comment: CRA uses dotenv in most cases to run dev build, prod build etc.

Comment: (Duplicate) Check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744375/create-react-app-using-environment-variables-in-index-html