# How to use environment variable as the react vite app title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, page-title

How to use environment variable as the react vite app title?

One solution I found is, In the `index.tsx` file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

// Set document title dynamically
document.title = import.meta.env.REACT_APP_MY_VARIABLE || 'Default Title';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

However, when using whatever value in

`export REACT_APP_MY_VARIABLE=whatever`

I alway ended up with `'Default Title'`.

Following
[Create React App: using environment variables in index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744375/create-react-app-using-environment-variables-in-index-html), I changed the above to `process.env`:

`document.title = process.env.REACT_APP_MY_VARIABLE || 'Default Title';`

but now my react app is only showing an empty page.

PS.

This is a react vite app, and I'm starting it with:

`npx vite --host`

PPS.

The solution has to be work for *both* dev/test time and build time.

Comment: Don't mix up (Create) React App and Vite: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for custom environment variables to be exposed in Vite, they need to prefixed with `VITE_`: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.

You probably want to use `import.meta.env.VITE_APP_TITLE` and set the `VITE_APP_TITLE` variable.