# Error on S3 due User deletion: "InvalidAccessKeyId - The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records." Where should I update keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, access-keys

My app was working normally, however I had to delete the user that set up the aws infrastructure due to unauthorised access. Now I cannot upload anything to the app. On console I got this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

> Response {type: "cors", url: "https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/", redirected: false, status: 403, ok: false, …}

And then on Sources I got this:

> `InvalidAccessKeyId`
>     The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

The code of the app is set up like this:

```
import { uploadFile } from 'react-s3';

const Services = {
    S3Upload: (file) => {
        const config = {
            bucketName: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
            region: process.env.S3_REGION,
            accessKeyId: process.env.S3_API_ACCESS_KEY,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_API_SECRET_KEY,
        };

        return uploadFile(file, config);
    },
};

export const { S3Upload } = Services;

export default Services;
```

Could you please help me update the access keys with the ones of my current user? It's diving me crazy. Thank you!

Comment: Is this app running on EC2? How are you actually running it (shell, pm2, service, other?)

Comment: Yes, it's running on EC2 and a RDS

Comment: RDS seems irrelevant to the question. How are you running the app?

Comment: Yes sorry. I was just specifying the services that it uses. It’s a basic web app running on EC2.

Comment: OK, let's ignore the questions about how you're running the app. You can clearly see from the code you've shown that it gets its AWS credentials from the environment in which the app runs. How that environment is provided to the app depends on how you run it, but if you're simply running the app from the shell, for example, then you need to set the environment variables e.g. `export S3_API_ACCESS_KEY=AKIAxxxx`. That said, you shouldn't be supplying credentials this way. They're IAM user credentials which are persistent and a security risk. You should configure the instance with an IAM role.

Comment: Alright. I just created a new AMI role, with full s3 access and I attached it to the EC2 instance. But still not working, what am I missing?

Comment: Hmm, I decided to go look at the third-party `react-s3` package you're using.  It doesn't seem to support STS credentials (which is what you get when you launch EC2 with an IAM role). Is there a particular reason that you're using this package? If you don't want to replace it, and I can understand why you might not want to, then you probably need to revert to the IAM user credential approach for now. You need to understand how your app is being run because that will explain how the environment variables get set. Once you know that, modify them to new IAM user credentials.

Comment: I’m sorry. But, what do you refer with how it’s being run? It’s an EC2 Instance using Amazon Linux. Connected to GitHub. Is that any helpful?

Comment: Apps don't run on their own. Something makes them run. That can be a human typing a command into the bash/zsh shell. That can be systemd on Linux. That can be a third-party process manager like pm2. And there are other ways. If you don't know how this app is started them you cannot know for certain how its environment is provided to it. I'd suggest that you find a developer who is familiar with this app, because they should know, or at least be able to find out.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. I investigated and it's not using a process manager. It's just a static web page app running with Parcel.

Comment: OK, sounds like you have some pre-processor for your web page such as html-webpack-plugin (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375867/how-do-you-reference-a-process-env-variable-in-html-script-src-react)) that populates environment variables, because the HTML page itself cannot access the local environment of the client from the user's browser.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find a trace of webpack in the project, but I can see that is using Dockerfile. In ENV is making a reference to NGINX. `ENV NGINX_ENTRYPOINT_QUIET_LOGS=1`